# how can i remove the social bookmark plugin using html or javascript

Tags: blogspot

sory guys, click the first link you will see the image i been mark by red, after you click the second link, you will see the arrow.

1) http://s261.beta.photobucket.com/user/minaekoz/media/satu.png.html

2) http://s261.beta.photobucket.com/user/minaekoz/media/satua.png.html

Question :

That is social bookmarking site i use to promote my blog but i want to remove the plugin after somebody click that link in the first image.

how can i remove that plugin in the second image after user click the link at the first image?

*sory if my english so bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your page is embedded, I guess it's done using frames or an iframe? This would be important to know, but you'll most likely be able to use some javascript code like this (called in some element's `onload` event (e.g. `<body>`):

```
if (window.top != window.self)
    window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href);
```

I think you can add it through using a custom BlogSpot template or maybe with some of the widgets as well.

Comment: Just keep in mind that this reloads your page, so it might skew your stats (in case you're tracking page impressions etc.).

Comment: it really works, thanks but i'm using blogspot platform, it got problem when i want to "edit html" in template tab, the page become blank.. i mean in the dashboard..any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, have you tried using another browser? Also you might be able to use the custom widget widget to insert the JavaScript code.

Comment: hmm..still can't..maybe coz blogspot..never mind..thanks mario..its not a big problem.. still can use it..just stop the loading page if i wan to edit the html code.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't. That social bookmarking site will probably open your website in an IFRAME, and therefore, clicks in your page cause IFRAME navigation, and not browser navigation.

Since your site, and the IFRAME site are different, the javascript in your site cannot access the DOM (Document Object Model) in the other site because SOP (Same Origin Policy).

You can disallow that your website run in IFRAMEs by using the [X-Frame-Options http header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) though, but I would leave it like that.

Cheers.